# Convert Integer value from database to textbox max length

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have a column in database where integer values are stored(4 ,6, 8...).
These integer values are supposed to be max allowed length of TextBox, this is the [Table](https://jsfiddle.net/rzhvk9fw/7/).

This is code from c# where I passed Characteristic names and integers(max number of places for textbox'es from database dynamically) for now.

```
protected void ddlBC_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //ddlKar.Items.Clear(); 
    LogicTableAdapters.getLvLOneIntegerTableAdapter getKar = new LogicTableAdapters.getLvLOneIntegerTableAdapter();

    DataTable dtKar = getKar.getLvLOneInteger(ddlBC.SelectedValue);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2]{ new DataColumn("CharacteristicName", typeof(string)) new DataColumn("MaxNoPlaces", typeof(string))});

    foreach (DataRow dr in dtKar.Rows)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(dr["CharacteristicName"].ToString(), dr["MaxNoPlaces"].ToString());
    }

    gvKarakteristike.DataSource = dt;
    gvKarakteristike.DataBind();
}
```

This is the asp part:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvKarakteristike" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="LevelID" OnRowDataBound="gvKarakteristike_RowDataBound">

            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Characteristics">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Characteristics" runat="server" Width="150px" Height="30px" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("CharacteristicName") %>'></asp:Label>


                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOpis" AppendDataBoundItems="true"  Width="142px" Height="35px" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" runat="server">
                             <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
                         </asp:DropDownList>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxOpis" runat="server" Width="130px" Height="28px" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" Text='<%# Bind("MaxNoPlaces") %>'></asp:TextBox>


                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>

            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />

        </asp:GridView>
```

I need to this dynamically directly from database because database will grow over time so will the number of textbox'es.

Can I maybe do this with jquery somehow or asp?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the below code and see if it works. I changed the Text attribute  to MaxLength.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxOpis" runat="server" Width="130px" Height="28px" Font-Names="Georgia" margin-Left="100px" MaxLength='<%= Bind("MaxNoPlaces") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping multiline might make it harder for you to set the textbox's max length. You can actually set the MaxLength dynamically by javascript. Check out this post: [Control maxlength of multiline textbox](http://michaelsync.net/2007/04/04/tipstricks-how-to-control-maxlength-of-multiline-textbox-in-aspnet-11)

Comment: Whenever you are referring another link, make sure of mentioning the crux of that so the reader can directly use your suggestion instead of navigating away.